# Count projectCard after forEach is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i retrieve data from firebase database and create cards for each array data i need calculate all cards which was created after foreach function. Could you please help?
here is a code:

```
function setProjects(){
    
    projects.forEach((project, projectId) => {
      //console.log(project);
      let projectCard = `
        <div id="project${projectId}" class="card project">
        
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title title">${project.title[currentLang]}</h5>
            <p class="card-text descr">${project.descr[currentLang]}</p>
            <h6><span class="badge badge-primary project-sector">${sectors[project.sector][currentLang]}</span></h6>
            <h6><span data-ru="${project.cost} млн" data-tj="${project.cost} млн" data-en="${project.cost} mln" 
            class="badge badge badge-secondary">${project.cost} млн $</span> </h6>
            <h6><span data-ru="${project.realization} г." data-tj="${project.realization}сол" data-en="${project.realization} years" class="badge badge badge-success">${project.realization} г.</span> </h6>
          </div>
        </div>`;
        
      $(".projects").append(projectCard); // добавим карту на страницу
      addMarkerToClusterer(project);
      
    });

    setMarkerClusterer();
    
    
  }
```

Comment: *i need calculate all cards* - what does this mean? calculate all cards? do you mean add all the costs? or do you need to know how many (your title suggests a count) ... that would be `projects.length`

Comment: So i have an array of projects in database firebase. i retrive this data and do foreach function in setProjects function also there i creating the card (projectCard) there put data of project which i got from firebase i need count how many cards (projectCard) was created at the page.

Comment: it would be projects.length

Comment: So i need count projectCard after foreach done

Comment: or use `projects.length`

Comment: If you are worried about availability of length property, just initialize a variable say `count` before forEach and `count++` inside forEach and then below you have it